# storing data from props of reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a function in actions which makes an api call.
index.js of actions

```
export const GET_QUERY_LIST='GET_QUERY_LIST';

export const loadData=()=>{
    return(dispatch)=>{
        axios({
            method:'GET',
            url:Constants.URLConst+"/Query,
            headers:Constants.headers
        }).then((response)=>{
            return dispatch({
                type:GET_QUERY_LIST,
                response
            });
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e);
        })
    }
}
```

The same function I am using in Reducers like this-

index.js of reducers

```
function getQueryData(state=[],action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_QUERY_LIST:
            return Object.assign({},state,{
                result_get_query:action.response
            })

        default:
                return state

    }
}

const data=combineReducers({
    getQueryData
})
```

export default data;

I am using this reducer function in my js file, say home.js as follows

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {loadData} from './actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Header from './Header.js';
// import './Home.css';

export class Home extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            querylist:[]
        }
        this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.loadData();

    }

    handleChange(){
        this.setState({
            querylist:this.props.resultCame
        })
    }

    render(){
        console.log("home.js",this.state.querylist);
        //this.props.resultCame.resultMeta.data.ProfileData.UserId
        if(this.props.resultCame.resultMeta){
        return( 
            <div> 
                <Header/>

                    <div>{this.handleChange()}</div>

            </div>          
            )
        }else{
            return null;
        }   
    }

}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    return{
        resultCame:state.getQueryData
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{
    loadData:loadData
})(Home);
```

I am storing the data in resultCame variable. In the render function if I do,

```
console.log(this.props.resultCame)
```

then the result comes which means the api is getting called properly, but I want to store the result in a state variable.So in `componentDidMount()` after calling the `loadData()`, I am setting the state in `querylist`.

But `this.state.querylist` is coming empty which means the data is not getting set.

How to set the data properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `axios` which works asynchronously. This means that it waits for the response to arrive from the API before doing anything. When you use `ComponentDidMount()` and call the action and then immediately call `setState`, the probable cause of `this.state.queryset` being empty is because it is assigned before `axios` has received anything from API call. You will have to `setState` after receiving response from `axios`, not just running it.

Comment: how should I do it?

Comment: You can use conditional rendering by checking `if(!this.state.resultCame)`. If there is nothing inside `this.state.resultCame`, it means `axios` has not completed yet. You could return a `loading div` until it does so. When the `axios` is complete, re-rendering will take place and as now `this.state.resultCame` has data, you can return desired HTML in `else`. Please **do not** `setState` inside render function. If it is a requirement to have a component state, you can use other lifecycle methods such as `ComponentShouldUpdate` to set component state.

Comment: is it working? and is it a requirement to have `querylist` property on `Home` component?

Comment: it goes into the else part and displays nothing

Comment: Of course. it will go in else because there is no data in `resultCame`. Return a div with some loading message instead of `null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156905/discussion-between-saad-khan-and-aayushi).

Comment: but when I am setting the state, shouldn't render be called again?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **ComponentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)** to update the state as the reply of the axios success call will come in the updated next props as you will be receiving them as the redux store on dispatch of 
**type:GET_QUERY_LIST,** payload.